# Swagger UI implementation for WCF service

Tags: wcf, swagger, swagger-wcf

How can i implement Swagger for WCF Rest service ?
I have referred following two solutions :

swaggerwcf:  [1]: https://github.com/abelsilva/swaggerwcf

Swaggeratr:  [2]: https://github.com/superstator/Swaggeratr

But , not able to find the way to achieve this.

If there is any other way. please suggest.

Comment: You can try using maybe Swagger4Wcf.
https://github.com/Virtuoze/Swagger4WCF

Comment: i tried both two swaggerwcf and swaggerattr, but i could not complete the implementation.